# PHP - Dealing with duplicated array keys (internal pointers)

Tags: php, arrays, pointers, key

I have the following lines of code that fetches some data from my database. I need to reference some specific contents of the data but I am having an issue with duplicated array keys. i do not want to sort through the data using SQL statements due to the complexity of the project.

Upon checking the pointers of the array, the following was generated. 
( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 )

A sample of the printed array :
( [0] => 3371450.18 ) Array ( [0] => 54459051.95 ) Array ( [0] => 210382.52 ) Array ( [0] => 6860440.01 ) Array ( [0] => 13131358.12 )

Since all the array keys are duplicated some PHP array functions like(array_sum, array_max) etc do work on the array and its getting really frustrating.

I wonder if this is because of the while loop. Are array pointers within a while loop always duplicated. 
   `

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sess']) && !empty(isset($_SESSION['sess']))){

echo "Session id is ".$_SESSION['sess']." exist";
$currentSession = $_SESSION['sess'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `loanbook` WHERE LoanBookSessionId='$currentSession'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbs,$sql);
$teamselection = "SELECT * FROM `Teams`";
$teamresult = mysqli_query($dbs,$teamselection);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

 ?>
 <?php
 $Sn[] = $row['Id'];
 $Team = $row['Team'];
 $CounterClass = $row['CounterPartyClassification'];
 $GrossL = $row['GrossLoan'];
 $CollType = $row['CollateralType'];

 print_r(array_keys(array($GrossL)));
 print_r((array($GrossL)));
 }

 ?>`
```

Comment: The code sample seems to be missing from your question, can you please add it back in.

Comment: It looks like you don't have an array with your data but instead an array full of arrays of 1 element with the data, so all of those inner arrays all have index 0 containing the information. Would have to analyze the code to understand why this is happening, probably something to do with using some class that abstracts the data like `SimpleXMLElement()`, `DOMDocument()` or equivalent.

Comment: When I pull data from `SimpleXMLElement()` I force a type conversion to fix this problem, like `$info = (double)$data->result` for instance, instead of a simple `$info = $data->result`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have a 2d array, where each of the inner arrays contains a string that represents a float.

Mapping each one of the inner arrays to a parsed float value should provide the data structure you need.

```
<?php

$x = [
    ["1.43434"],
    ["1.43434"],
];

echo json_encode($x) . "\n";

echo json_encode(array_map(function($t) {
    return floatval($t[0]);
}, $x));
```

output

```
▶ php test.php
[["1.43434"],["1.43434"]]
[1.43434,1.43434]
```

Comment: I just tried it. The problem still exists. all the array keys are still 0.

Comment: ["3371450.18"] ["54459051.95"] ["210382.52"] ["6860440.01"] ["13131358.12"] ["1137406895"] ["285531147.5"] ["27719631.45"] ["21699617.25"] ["50705852.68"] ["25768709.1"] ["25655094.18"] ["33686018.46"] ["416219707.6"] ["41835640.04"] ["709347.92"] ["1269608.96"] ["2756794.56"] ["2772667.97"] ["20439.25"] ["10429746.8"] ["1487394.99"] ["1499122.27"] ["6789633.61"] ["1419328.15"] ["10328881.42"] ["32304411.56"] ["69602729.01"]